# Execute .jar file through Mozilla Add-on

Tags: javascript, mozilla, jpm

I have been trying to find a way to execute a .jar file using Mozilla JPM (I am well aware that an add-on that accomplishes this exists but I want to learn). I followed the online tutorial and this is my code right now

```
var buttons = require('sdk/ui/button/action');
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");

var button = buttons.ActionButton({
  id: "mozilla-link",
  label: "Visit Mozilla",
  icon: {
    "16": "./icon-16.png",
    "32": "./icon-32.png",
    "64": "./icon-64.png"
  },
 onClick: handleClick
});

function handleClick(state) {
  tabs.open("C:\Users\QaziWa\Documents\Jar\DownloadReportPPE.jar");
}
```

Now I have successfully opened URLs but I cannot find any documentation on how to execute a jar file. My code above:

```
tabs.open("C:\Users\QaziWa\Documents\Jar\DownloadReportPPE.jar");
```

is clearly incorrect.

I was looking at this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/tabs, but I failed to find anything that presents the ability to execute a jar file.

My aim is to create an add-on button that will execute this jar file for me. This jar file downloads pdf reports on a website so I would like it to execute in a new tab or window. What method will give me what I am looking for or is there any documentation that can help me.

Comment: Given that jar files are java applications, not something a browser can execute on its own: if you don't want to pack them as webstart applications, or as applet (both are kind of dead in the browser world, with java having fallen from grace) what are you trying to actually do? I suspect that whatever your .jar application does, modern JS can probably also do.

Comment: I just recently started a co-op term at a company and I was asked to figure out a way to execute a .jar file from within the Mozilla Firefox browser. The .jar file was created by a developer here and handed to me for this task. Essentially the purpose of this task is to give clients a way to execute the .jar file with a simple click within their browser.

Comment: sounds like you've been asked to reinvent [java webstart](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart).

Comment: Forgive me if I am incorrect but wouldn't a Java Webstart Application be executed by clicking a link on a web page? What I am trying to do is create a Mozilla Firefox extension that will execute a .jar file.

Comment: yes - so make an extension that automatically clicks webstart links with specific-to-your-organisation ids/class combinations and done? (although be aware that Mozilla is changing the way its extension framework works soon, detailed [here](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2015/08/21/the-future-of-developing-firefox-add-ons/))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely not the best solution but I figured out something that works.

The following code will execute a .jar file by clicking the Mozilla add-on button:

```
var buttons = require('sdk/ui/button/action');

var button = buttons.ActionButton({
  id: "execute-jar",
  label: "Download Report",
  icon: {
    "16": "./icon-16.png",
    "32": "./icon-32.png",
    "64": "./icon-64.png"
    //Icons for the button
  },
  onClick: handleClick
});



function handleClick(state) {   

    let {Cc, Ci} = require('chrome');
    var file = Cc["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsILocalFile);
    file.initWithPath("C:\\Users\\QaziWa\\DownloadReportPPE.jar");

    if(file.exists()){
        file.reveal();
        file.launch();
    }
    else {
        console.log('Failed.');
    }
}
```